# How to remain visible for 1 second and then go back to Hidden in visibility in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a style for ScrollBar. 
The track in ScrollBar have Visibility Hidden by default.
It change to Visible if either: 
 - the mouse is over the scroll bar
 - or, the user is currently scrolling using the scroll wheel
Once the condition for visibility is not fulfilled anymore, How to remain the track is visible for 1 second and then go back to Hidden ?

Thanks!

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBarTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid Width="15">
        <Border Opacity="0.7"/>
        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" 
            Width="12"
            MinHeight="20"
            Height="Auto"
            Margin="2"
            IsDirectionReversed="true" >
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBackgroundStyle}" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"  />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBackgroundStyle}" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Name="Thumb" Visibility="Hidden" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbStyle}" />
            </Track.Thumb>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>                
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I try use:

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="FadeInStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb" 
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
             From="0" To="1"  Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="FadeOutStoryboard" BeginTime="0:0:1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 From="1" To="0"  Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    </Storyboard>

<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions><
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeOutStoryboard}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
```

But that not remain the track is visible for 1 second and then go back to Hidden unless I set the track in ScrollBar have Visibility Visible by default.
Thanks!

Comment: You could animate the Thumb's Opacity property from 0 to 100% over one second when the mouse enters and leaves the Scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply  FreddyFlares.

Comment: FreddyFlares, I tried but ineffective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `Setter` where you set the `Visibility` to `Visible`. Once the `IsMouseOver` property changes value to false, the trigger will automatically set the `Visibility` back to `Hidden`. To fix that, you'll have to animate the `Visibility` property and remove the `Setter` from the trigger.

Example storyboards:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FadeInStoryboard">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0%" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" From="0"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="FadeOutStoryboard" >
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" From="1" BeginTime="0:0:1"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                     To="0" />
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:1" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="Thumb" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="100%" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

**Edit:**
This is one possible way to trigger the same behavior when scrolling with the mouse wheel. I just quickly created this, so check it before you use it and expect it to be robust. You have to create a new class and derive it from `ScrollViewer`:

```
public class ScrollViewerEx : ScrollViewer {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsScrollingWithMouseWheelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsScrollingWithMouseWheel", typeof (bool), typeof (ScrollViewerEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsScrollingWithMouseWheel {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsScrollingWithMouseWheelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsScrollingWithMouseWheelProperty, value); }
    }

    private readonly DispatcherTimer mouseWheelActivityTimer;

    public ScrollViewerEx() {
        mouseWheelActivityTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        mouseWheelActivityTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        mouseWheelActivityTimer.Tick += MouseWheelActivityTimerOnTick;
    }

    private void MouseWheelActivityTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
        mouseWheelActivityTimer.Stop();
        IsScrollingWithMouseWheel = false;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
        mouseWheelActivityTimer.Stop();
        IsScrollingWithMouseWheel = true;
        mouseWheelActivityTimer.Start();
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

Add the following `DataTrigger` to the `ControlTemplate` of the `ScrollBar`:
**Note:** This stops the `BeginStoryboard`s explicitly, and you'll need to add the `StopStoryboard`s to the existing `Trigger` in the `ControlTemplate` aswell, otherwise the last `Trigger` will block the first `Trigger`.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=data:ScrollViewerEx}, Path=IsScrollingWithMouseWheel}" 
             Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeOut"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" Name="fadeIn"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeIn"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeOutStoryboard}" Name="fadeOut"/>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

**Edit 2:** This is another approach, using an attached property and `EventTrigger`.

You'll have to adapt the `ControlTemplate` of the `ScrollViewer` to add the following `EventTrigger`:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseWheel">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(data:ScrollViewerProperties.IsScrollingWithMouseWheel)">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0%" Value="True"/>
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

And create a class to define the attached property in, something like this:

```
public static class ScrollViewerProperties {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsScrollingWithMouseWheelProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsScrollingWithMouseWheel", typeof (bool), typeof (ScrollViewerProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public static void SetIsScrollingWithMouseWheel(DependencyObject element, bool value) {
        element.SetValue(IsScrollingWithMouseWheelProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsScrollingWithMouseWheel(DependencyObject element) {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(IsScrollingWithMouseWheelProperty);
    }
}
```

And update the `DataTrigger` in the `ScrollBar` template to use the attached property like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}},Path=(data:ScrollViewerProperties.IsScrollingWithMouseWheel)}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeOut"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" Name="fadeIn"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeIn"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeOutStoryboard}" Name="fadeOut"/>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Can you help me for It change to Visible if: the user is currently scrolling using the scroll wheel ?. Thank you so much !

Comment: @Mr.Le edited the answer, can you mark this as the answer if this helps you out?

Comment: thank you for your enthusiastic support. Do you have any solutions without creating a new class?
eg using: <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseWheel">. I'm currently testing on your way !

Comment: It is possible to use an `EventTrigger`, but you'll still need a property to trigger the behavior in the `ScrollBar`, see Edit #2

Comment: @Roel I don't know why you need to change the Visibility when the Opacity is zero, it won't be visible anyway right?

Comment: @Mr.Le You could use an EventTrigger on the ScrollChanged event and put a Storyboard in there.

Comment: @Roel van Westerop: I tried use the solution of you in Edit and Edit 2. But it is inefficient. <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource SimpleListBoxStyle}">. I want trigger the same behavior when scrolling with the mouse wheel when the mouse is inside the ListBox

Comment: @FreddyFlares: Thank you for your interest. But, your solution does not really effect me

Comment: @Roel van Westerop: yeah! Edit 2 work fine. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Roel van Westerop:i scrolling mouse, the strack is visible. I move mouse over the scroll bar while i scrolling mouse, then i stop scrolling mouse, the strack is hidden although the mouse over the scroll bar. How do I fix this?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this in Xaml, but there might be a way to solve this with a behavior controlling the storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete a brilliant @Roel van Westerop comment.
I've tried **Edit 2** by myself. It works great, except one little thing. Instead of using just DataTrigger, a better aproach is to use MultiDataTrigger like this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
     <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
           <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                      {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}},
                       Path=(data:ScrollViewerProperties.IsScrollingWithMouseWheel)}" Value="True"/>
           <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},
                                        Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>                                
     </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
     <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeOut"/>
          <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="
                                {StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" Name="fadeIn"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
           <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeIn"/>
           <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" Name="fadeOut"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

This MultiDataTrigger fixes the bug, when you have a mouse over a scrollbar, and use MouseWheel to scroll the content (without this multitrigger the scrollbar will fadeout even with mouseover on it)